# Join get wrong information on query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm having some problems with join query. What I want is select rows of two tables that have some similar states, others no. And I have a state-equivalence view

```
Table Sales:
ID  .....   StateID
1           1
2           1
3           6

Table Orders
ID  .....   StateID
11          2
12          2
15          3

Table StatesEquivalence
ID  SalesState   OrdersState    StateName
1   1            2              Attended
2   2            3              Declined
```

I've made a union of both tables(Sales and Orders) and I want a column with the EquivalentStateID and the StateName by doing something like this:

```
SELECT sales.ID as ID,equivalence.ID as State,equivalence.StateName
FROM Sales
INNER JOIN StatesEquivalence as equivalence
ON sales.StateID = equivalence.SalesState
WHERE sales.ID = 1
UNION
SELECT orders.ID as ID,equivalence.ID as State,equivalence.StateName
FROM Orders as orders
INNER JOIN StatesEquivalence as equivalence
ON orders.StateID = equivalence.OrdersState
```

Somehow I am obtaining wrong information on the equivalentID

```
ID      State        StateName
1       2            Attended
2       2            Attended
11      2            Attended
...
```

I don't know what happend.. because the statename is correct, but the StateID is showing wrong information

The table might show this:

```
ID      State        StateName
1       1            Attended
2       1            Attended
11      1            Attended
...
```

Comment: What's your actual query? `WHERE sales.ID = 1` doesn't match results, also `equivalent.ID` vs. `StatesEquivalence as equivalence`..

Comment: From your description and the query you've shown, I see nothing wrong with it. Could you post what you've expected and add a comment if a resulting row originates from sales or orders. Also, be complete. I would expect ID 15 to be in the result but it isn't.

Comment: Yes It matches, as a result it give the first row of Sales table.

Comment: @Juan, where does ID 2 in results come from then? And `equivalent` / `equivalence`? If you've simplified the query for us, you may have removed the problem code.

Comment: Make sure you're getting ID and StateName from the "equivalence" alias.  Right now you're trying to use the "equivalent" alias and I don't see that defined anywhere.

Comment: `ID` 11 is from `orders`. `orders` does not have a `stateid` 1. Do you expect the `sales.StateID` to be shown in the `orders` subselect?

Comment: @JuanCarlosVegaNeira - You should clarify how the `StatesEquivalence` table should be read, what does the column `ID` mean on that table?, should be used on the join condition?

Comment: @Lamak the ID of StatesEquivalence is the state column on the result table. the match column of the inner join depende on what table is making the join, if the query join with Orders, will use the OrdersStates column of the StatesEquivalence  table and show the ID of StatesEquivalence as the State on the resultant table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you are showing us the real problem code. I did the following:

```
begin transaction

create table sales (id int, stateid int)
create table orders (id int, stateid int)
create table statesequivalence (id int, salesstate int, ordersstate int, statename varchar(20))

insert into sales values (1, 1)
insert into sales values (2, 1)
insert into sales values (3, 6)

insert into orders values (11, 2)
insert into orders values (12, 2)
insert into orders values (15, 3)

insert into statesequivalence values (1, 1, 2, 'Attended')
insert into statesequivalence values (2, 2, 3, 'Declined')

SELECT sales.ID as ID,equivalence.ID as State,equivalence.statename
FROM Sales
INNER JOIN statesequivalence as equivalence
ON sales.StateID = equivalence.SalesState
WHERE sales.ID = 1
UNION
SELECT orders.ID as ID,equivalence.ID as State,equivalence.StateName
FROM Orders as orders
INNER JOIN statesequivalence as equivalence
ON orders.StateID = equivalence.OrdersState

rollback
```

Result:

```
ID          State       statename
----------- ----------- --------------------
1           1           Attended
11          1           Attended
12          1           Attended
15          2           Declined
```

So, it works. Can you try the above code?

Comment: Not that is matters for the final result but you've switched the `declined/accepted` records

Answer (score 1):

Following is a testscript and the output from your statement.
Perhaps it's easier to work from here and you tell us what is wrong with this output.

*The testscript can be adjusted and executed [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta/query/60251/join-gets-wrong-information-on-query)*

**Output**

```
ID          State       StateName
----------- ----------- ---------
1           1           Attended
11          1           Attended
12          1           Attended
15          2           Declined
```

**Test Script**

```
;WITH Sales AS (
  SELECT * FROM (VALUES
    (1, 1)
    , (2, 1)
    , (3, 6)
  ) AS Sales (ID, StateID)
)
, Orders AS (
  SELECT * FROM (VALUES
    (11, 2)
    , (12, 2)
    , (15, 3)
  ) AS Orders (ID, StateID)
)
, StatesEquivalence AS (
  SELECT * FROM (VALUES
    (1, 1, 2, 'Attended')
    , (2, 2, 3, 'Declined')
  ) AS StatesEquivalence (ID, SalesState, OrdersState, StateName)
)
SELECT  sales.ID as ID
        , equivalence.ID as State
        , equivalence.StateName
FROM    Sales
        INNER JOIN StatesEquivalence as equivalence ON sales.StateID = equivalence.SalesState
WHERE   sales.ID = 1
UNION
SELECT  orders.ID as ID
        , equivalence.ID as State
        , equivalence.StateName
FROM    Orders as orders
        INNER JOIN StatesEquivalence as equivalence ON orders.StateID = equivalence.OrdersState
```

Comment: I think is because on my sales table i have more states that ar not on the equivalence table

Comment: @JuanCarlosVegaNeira - That does not clear anything up for me. Can you add a (or more) records to the testscript to show us where the results are not what you expect them to be?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand what you need exactly, but maybe is this?

```
select *
from StatesEquivalence EQ
full join Sales S on EQ.SalesState = S.StateId
full join Orders O on EQ.OrdersState = O.StateId
```

This is a starting point maybe...